# file.exists returns different results on Windows versus Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, file

I know it's technically a bug to append whitespace around file names, but I'd just like to know why the following code returns true on Windows, but false on Linux:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("some_file_that_exists ");  // note the whitespace at the end
    System.out.println(file.exists());
}
```

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with jdk1.6.0_31, and retried on Linux 2.6.18 with jdk1.6.0_06. Note that the file does not have a space at the end of its name.

Comment: Which version of Java? Also, does the file really have a space at the end of the name?

Comment: @fge I used 1.6. And the filename does not have a space at the end.

Comment: May be because windows does not allow space at end, and when java calls OS, OS removes/does not consider space at end. Whereas, linux allows space at end, so does exact check.

Comment: This is where it happens, for windows: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/jdk/src/windows/native/java/io/WinNTFileSystem_md.c#getFileInformation and it seems to call [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows API.

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with Java 7+ and `Files.exists()`?

Comment: @fge I tried with Java 7 on Windows and the same behavior exists. I also tried with `Files.exists()` and it failed with an exception when a trailing space exists.

Comment: @Batty I think what you're saying is right... This is probably the explanation. Can you add this as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, theoretical explanation. Couldn't find proof. Searching for it though. :)

Comment: What exception? An `InvalidPathException`?

Comment: No exception, exists returns false.

Comment: @fge Yes I think that was what I got when I used `Files.exists()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be because windows does not allow space at end, and when java calls OS, OS removes/does not consider space at end.

Whereas, linux allows space at end, so it does exact check and tries to find file with spaces at end of file name.